# Android/Kotlin Material Button checkedId, what is it?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

Wonder if anyone can tell me what exactly the `checkedId` of a Material Button is? The documentation is not very clear. For instance:

```
button.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked -> stuff e.g. Toast}
```

For the `checkedId`, I get a long integer. For instance, I have a button with XML ID `android:id="@+id/paletteF"`, and when I click it the `checkedId` returns as `2131362134`. I don't see an obvious correlation here, if there is one... Is it an address??

Comment: Did you compare that number to `R.id.paletteF`?

Comment: Okay, so `compareValues(R.id.paletteF, indexDiatonic) == 0` returns `true` (which I didn't expect). Is the Int some kind of number representation of the string "paletteF"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it is useful to understand that Android has a generated class called `R` which contains identifiers for all of your XML declared resources. So every time you declare `@+id/newId` in an XML file, a new static field (an integer) is created in the `R` class representing that ID, namely `R.id.newID`.

So in answer to your question, the `checkedId` refers to the same ID that `android:id="@+id/paletteF"` does and to check them programmatically you would would something like:

```
checkedId == R.id.paletteF
```

---

Just as a side note, this was an oversimplification of the `R` class but if you're interested there's plenty of information out there, some of it on this forum.

Comment: Interesting, thank you, I didn't know that, but this clarifies quite a lot. I ended up using a solution like what you suggest.